# crash application when starting new Activity with large background

Tags: java, android, android-activity

when i try to click on button to move to the second Activity the app crash (unfortunately  app has stopped ). The main Activity and the second Activity was created with a background image.

I have tried to delete the backgrounds and replace it with mipmap so the app run very well without crashing. I don't know why ?
PS: the size of backrounds jpg = 70kb and 80 kb.

[image: look at the java main & drawable folder]

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of your code, paste the actual relevant code here along with the stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: `ios`? `android-studio`? do NOT spam with irrelevant tags!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you described, I guess the exception is `OutOfMemory` exception. This is a well-known issue when you load a large image into activity. You should scale that image down before loading into `ImageView`

Here is the sample code getting from [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```